# How should I pass input value with Redux without using this.state and setState

Tags: reactjs, redux

As I am learning Redux, I managed to use Provider, use child component, connect them etc.

But I have form in child component, I want to pass data from child to parent but on  Submit. I don't want to use 'value onChange setState value' method. I want to use Redux with this.

I can also think of doing onChange dispatch but I want to pass values once onSubmit happens only.

```
import React from "react";

class InputComponent extends React.Component {
  addNewTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e.target);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.addNewTodo}>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control form-control-lg addTodoform"
          id='addTodoform'
          placeholder="Add new task or note"
          defaultValue=''
        />
        <button type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' >
          Add
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default InputComponent;
```

Comment: have you defined a redux reducer, and an action for the submit?

Comment: I want to console log the value of the input first then I will pass it to the store with dispatch and reducer. I can do the action reducer part but how can I pass input value without setState?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want would be to use the `document` API to access the value of the form input `addTodoform` like so:

```
const inputValue = document.getElementById('addTodoform').value;
```

So, in your `addNewTodo()` handler, you might do the following:

```
class InputComponent extends React.Component {
  addNewTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e.target);

    // Get value from input directly, without the use of setState, etc
    const inputValue = document.getElementById('addTodoform').value;

    // Dispatch inputValue to your redux action
    // dispatch(submitAction(inputValue))
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.addNewTodo}>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control form-control-lg addTodoform"
          id='addTodoform'
          placeholder="Add new task or note"
          defaultValue=''
        />
        <button type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' >
          Add
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps